# multiprocess initializer and pickling

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I've been playing around with [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) and trying to understand how exactly the `initializer` argument works. From what I understand, the initializer function is called for each process, so I assumed the arguments to it (i.e. `initargs`) would have to be pickled across process boundaries. I know that the `map` method of a pool also uses pickling for its arguments, so I assumed that anything that works as an argument for the initializer should also work as an argument for mapping.

However, when I run the following piece of code, `initialize` gets called just fine, but then `map` throws an exception about not being able to pickle the module. (There's nothing special about using the current module as the argument; it was just the first non-pickleable object that came to mind.) Does anyone know what could be behind this difference?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import multiprocessing
import sys


def get_pid():
    return multiprocessing.current_process().pid


def initialize(module):
    print('Got module {} in PID {}'.format(module, get_pid()))


def worker(module):
    print('Got module {} in PID {}'.format(module, get_pid()))


current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
work = [current_module]

print('Main process has PID {}'.format(get_pid()))
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None, initialize, work)
pool.map(worker, work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize doesn't require pickling, but the `map` call does. Maybe this will shed some light…  (here I'm using `multiprocess` instead of `multiprocessing` to give better pickling and interactivity).

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> import multiprocess as multiprocessing
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> def get_pid():
...     return multiprocessing.current_process().pid
... 
>>> 
>>> def initialize(module):
...     print('Got module {} in PID {}'.format(module, get_pid()))
... 
>>> 
>>> def worker(module):
...     print('Got module {} in PID {}'.format(module, get_pid()))
... 
>>> 
>>> current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
>>> work = [current_module]
>>> 
>>> print('Main process has PID {}'.format(get_pid()))
Main process has PID 34866
>>> pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(None, initialize, work)
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
>>> pool.map(worker, work)
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34866
[None]
```

Cool. The threading `pool` works… (because it doesn't need to pickle anything).  How about when we are shipping both `worker` and `work` using serialization?

```
>>> pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None, initialize, work)
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34875
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34876
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34877
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34878
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34879
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34880
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34881
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34882
>>> pool.map(worker, work)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess-0.70.4.dev0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/multiprocess/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess-0.70.4.dev0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/multiprocess/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled
>>>
```

So let's look at pickling `work`:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> import sys            
>>> pickle.dumps(sys.modules[__name__])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
>>>
```

So, you can't pickle a module… ok, can we do better using `dill`?

```
>>> import dill
>>> dill.detect.trace(True)
>>> dill.pickles(work)
M1: <module '__main__' (built-in)>
F2: <function _import_module at 0x10c017cf8>
# F2
D2: <dict object at 0x10d9a8168>
M2: <module 'dill' from '/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/__init__.pyc'>
# M2
F1: <function worker at 0x10c07fed8>
F2: <function _create_function at 0x10c017488>
# F2
Co: <code object worker at 0x10b053cb0, file "<stdin>", line 1>
F2: <function _unmarshal at 0x10c017320>
# F2
# Co
D1: <dict object at 0x10af68168>
# D1
D2: <dict object at 0x10c0e4a28>
# D2
# F1
M2: <module 'sys' (built-in)>
# M2
F1: <function initialize at 0x10c07fe60>
Co: <code object initialize at 0x10b241f30, file "<stdin>", line 1>
# Co
D1: <dict object at 0x10af68168>
# D1
D2: <dict object at 0x10c0ea398>
# D2
# F1
M2: <module 'pathos' from '/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pathos-0.2a1.dev0-py2.7.egg/pathos/__init__.pyc'>
# M2
C2: __future__._Feature
# C2
D2: <dict object at 0x10b05b7f8>
# D2
M2: <module 'multiprocess' from '/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess-0.70.4.dev0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/multiprocess/__init__.pyc'>
# M2
T4: <class 'pathos.threading.ThreadPool'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x10c0ea5c8>
# D2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 1209, in pickles
    pik = copy(obj, **kwds)
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 161, in copy
    return loads(dumps(obj, *args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 197, in dumps
    dump(obj, file, protocol, byref, fmode, recurse)#, strictio)
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 190, in dump
    pik.dump(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 1116, in save_module
    state=_main_dict)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 768, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess-0.70.4.dev0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/multiprocess/pool.py", line 452, in __reduce__
    'pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled'
NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled
>>>
```

The answer is **yes** -- the module starts to pickle, however, fails due to the contents in the module… so it looks like it works for everything in `__main__` except when there's an instance of a `pool` in `__main__` -- then it will fail.

So, if your last two lines of code were replaced with this one, it will work:

```
>>> multiprocessing.Pool(None, initialize, work).map(worker, work)
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34922
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34923
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34924
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34925
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34926
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34927
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34928
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34929
Got module <module '__main__' (built-in)> in PID 34922
[None]
>>>
```

That's using `multiprocess`, as it uses `dill` under the covers.  `pickle` will still fail to pickle here because `pickle` can't serialize a module.  Serialization is needed, as the object have to be sent to another python instance on another process.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, and for introducing me to the `multiprocess` module :) Does the `initializer` argument not need to pickle because it can just access the original memory directly (since all the processes will be spawned via `fork`)?

Comment: Just confirmed this by setting the [start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) to be `spawn`, which indeed requires the arguments to the initializer function to be pickleable. Thanks again!